# Python Calculator code not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have recently got a raspberry pi and I'm learning how to code on python using it. I also have a raspberry user guide and I'm copying out the calculator script but it's not working, can you help???
this is my script;

```
username = raw_input("What is your name?    ")
print ("Welcome to the program,",username
goAgain == 1
while goAgain == 1:
num1 = int(raw_input("type the first number"))   
num2 = int(raw_input("type the second number"))   
print num1, "added to", num2, "equals", num1 + num2   
print num1, "minus", num2, "equals", num1 - num2   
print num1, "multiplied by", num2, "equals", num1 * num2   
goAgain = int(raw_input("Type 1 to enter more numbers, or any other number to quit: "))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *but it's not working* is **not** a problem description. *How* is it not working? Please provide sample input, expected output, actual output and any tracebacks and exceptions you might see.

Comment: So many reasons... :(

Comment: Most probably you are having `SyntaxError` exceptions, because a lot of your code is either missing a closing parenthesis or using equality tests (`==`) where you wanted to use assignment (`=`), or are not indenting your code correctly (although that's probably an artifact of how you didn't format your question correctly).

Answer (score 1):

```
username = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
print ("Welcome to the program, ", username)

goAgain = 1 # <<< Equality check instead of assignment.

while goAgain == 1:
    num1 = int(raw_input("type the first number: "))
    num2 = int(raw_input("type the second number: "))

    print num1, "added to", num2, "equals", num1 + num2
    print num1, "minus", num2, "equals", num1 - num2
    print num1, "multiplied by", num2, "equals", num1 * num2

    goAgain = int(raw_input(
        "Type 1 to enter more numbers, "
        "or any other number to quit: "
    ))
```

[image]

PS: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help -> use spaces to indent your code block correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your code has open parenthesis and a equal to sign(`==`) instead of a assignment symbol(`=`). You also have an `IndentionError` in your program. The fixed code is like this:

```
username = raw_input("What is your name?    ")
print ("Welcome to the program,",username)
goAgain = 1
while goAgain == 1:
    num1 = int(raw_input("type the first number"))   
    num2 = int(raw_input("type the second number"))   
    print num1, "added to", num2, "equals", num1 + num2   
    print num1, "minus", num2, "equals", num1 - num2   
    print num1, "multiplied by", num2, "equals", num1 * num2   
    goAgain = int(raw_input("Type 1 to enter more numbers, or any other number to quit: "))
```

This should work